# ScrollView contents update

Tags: java, android, textview, scrollview, handler

I have a programmatically generated `ScrollView` with a `TextView` inside of it. I wish to update the text in the `TextView` from time to time and some have implemented a handler function to update the `TextView` GUI element. This seems to call/work correctly.

However, currently the only way I have found to *actually* get the `TextView` to show the appended information is to call:

```
consoleText.append("New text to add to TextView");
// then:
myScrollView.removeView(myTextView);
myScrollView.addView(myTextView);
```

This is not particularity optimal and was wondering how else I can refresh the contents of the `ScrollView` to show my newly added information...

Also:

```
invalidate();
postvalidate();
```

Do not seem to do anything - the `TextView` object has the new text in it (looking in debug) it's just not drawing it to the screen unless I call the add/remove function.

Thanks for any information/help you can give

FR

Comment: Is the append function calling setText() on the textview under the hood?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should call `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` on the TextView, and perhaps the ScrollView.

Comment: consoleText.invalidate();
consoleText.requestLayout();

That did it thanks :)

Comment: Calling `invalidate()` and `requestLayout` on `ScrollView` solved my problem of view clipping as well. Thanks!